# What is PSEUDO in V$PROCESS?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm Oracle Database beginner.

I read throughout Oracle reference, thought I cannot find an explanation of PSEUDO when I query V$PROCESS tables.

What is the role of it?

Below is example.

```
SQL> SELECT PID, SPID, PNAME,USERNAME, SERIAL#, PROGRAM FROM V$PROCESS;

PID        SPID                     PNAME USERNAME        SERIAL#    PROGRAM                                         
---------- ------------------------ ----- --------------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------
         1                                                         0 PSEUDO                                          
         2 19784                    PMON  oracle                   1 oracle@ol7_stby (PMON)
```

Comment: While APC is correct regarding PID=1, don't forget that the value for the `PROGRAM`column is supplied by the client connecting to the server. So you can't really rely on that information for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that its PID is 1 is not a coincidence: it is the Oracle startup program.

You may also see `PSEUDO` for sessions which have been killed and not yet cleaned up.